# Is there a way to know about the upcoming ICOs?

Tags: ether, dapps, tokens

I was just wandering if there is a place that lists all the upcoming Initial Coin Offerings that take place on Ethereum?

Comment: Here's one site - https://www.ico-list.com/

Comment: [Reddit ethtrader](http://reddit.com/r/ethtrader) may be a better place to ask.

Comment: Subscribe to TokenMarket's ICO calendar and you'll get a notification email every time any ICO is about to open or close: http://tokenmarket.net/ico-calendar